# Exporting from QGIS to NEXTGIS gives errors?

Tags: qgis-2.18, nextgis

Exporting a project from QGIS 2,18 into my new Mini Plan account at NEXTGIS and some of the jpeg files are not successful.
I get the error:

> {"exception": "ValidationError", "message": "Raster files without
>   projection info are not supported.", "attr": "source", "serializer":
>   "raster_layer"}

The projection info is surely there as the images/maps show up correctly within QGIS.

Can anyone explain this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jpeg files usually has no projection from a scratch (exclude additional world file is present). The map can show properly if it projection is the same as jpeg (even jpeg has no world file). But during uploading to your web GIS on nextgis.com the reprojection step is executed. So the projection must be defined. Please provide your sample data to NextGIS (support@nextgis.com) to solve your problem.

**Disclaimer**: I'm a developer at NextGIS.